# How to add comma and and in String in SQL

Tags: sql, loops, replace, sql-server-2012

I have a field IN SQL Item_Name and row as ITEM1,ITEM2,ITEM3 and ITEM4
I converted these rows as a single column with comma separated vales like ITEM1,ITEM2,ITEM3,ITEM4. How can I convert this column as ITEM1,ITEM2,ITEM3 and ITEM4.I need an and in the end item. Can I use replace in a loop?

This is my Scenario.
It is all about courses and pre requisite courses

```
COURSE_ID   PRE_COURSE_ID    OPERATOR
--------------------------------------------
IT105       IT100            AND
IT105       IT101              
IT106       1T103
BM110       BM101            AND
BM110       BM102            AND
BM110       BM103
CC107       CC103            OR
CC107       CC104
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Now I am expecting the output like below;

```
COURSE_ID PRE_COURSE_ID
------------------------
IT105     IT100 and IT101
IT106     IT103
BM110     BM101,BM102 and BM103
CC107     CC103 OR CC104
```

For operator "or" comma is not needed even though there are more than two courses.

Comment: Why do you store this as single value at all? Leave it as it is and store it in multiple rows.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Sorry if my question is not clear.I will explain it

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp (name NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES('ITEM1'),('ITEM2'),('ITEM3')

    SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT *
            FROM (
                SELECT ',' + name AS [text()]
                FROM #tmp
            )q
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,1,'')
    DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Comment: Thanks Chanom, I changed your answer to  ` SELECT STUFF((
            SELECT *
            FROM (
                SELECT ' and ' + name AS [text()]
                FROM #tmp
            )q
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ),1,4,'')   `   which will give me  ITEM1 and ITEM2 and ITEM3.Bit I need the output as  ITEM1 , ITEM2 and ITEM3.Thanks for the time and help

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Tim, you should  not try to store the values as comma seperated values. It would create many issues later on for you.

But if you want to know how you can do it then you can try like this in Sql Server:

```
declare @str varchar(1000)

SELECT @str= coalesce(@str + ', ', '') + x.mycol
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT mycol from mytable) x

print @str
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Sorry my question is not clear.Let me explain with a clear scenario. It is about courses and pre-requisite with operator. The table is like below.